# RGB32 byte array memory access optimization

Tags: c++, memory, optimization, directshow, rgb

I do not know much about lower level memory optimization but I am trying to figure out how to optimize memory access from a unsigned char array holding rbg32 data.

I am building a directshow transform filter (CTransInPlaceFilter) that needs to average areas of the data. The data given to me is in rgb32 format (`B G R 0xFF B G R 0xFF B G R 0xFF etc`). I am looping the data and calculating the average red, green and blue channels.

I find when I get dereference the data in the byte array the video playing runs the CPU up and without and accessing, the CPU doesn't do so much work.

After reading a bunch of posts, I think this is a memory to CPU bandwidth bottleneck.

Here is the code for the transform function:

> HRESULT CFilter::Transform(IMediaSample *pSample) {
>
> ```
> BYTE* data = NULL;
> pSample->GetPointer(&data);
>
> if (mVideoType == MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB32) {
>     Rect roi(0, 0, 400, 400);           // Normally this is dynamic
>     int totalPixels = roi.width * roi.height;
>
>     // Find the average color
>     unsigned int totalR = 0, totalG = 0, totalB = 0;
>     for (int r = 0; r < roi.height; r++) {
>         int y = roi.y + r;
>         BYTE* pixel = data + (roi.x + y * mWidth) * 4;      // 4 bytes per pixel
>
>         for (int c = 0; c < roi.width; c++) {
>             totalB += *pixel;           // THESE 3 LINES IS THE ISSUE
>             totalG += *(++pixel);
>             totalR += *(++pixel);
>             pixel++;
>         }
>     }
>     int meanR = (int)floor(totalR / totalPixels);
>     int meanG = (int)floor(totalG / totalPixels);
>     int meanB = (int)floor(totalB / totalPixels);
>     // Does work with the averaged data
> }
> return S_OK; }
> ```

So when I run the video without the 3 dereferencing lines I get about 10-14% cpu usage. With those lines I get 30-34% cpu usage.

I also tried to copy the data to a buffer to access the data.

```
mempy(mData, data, mWidth * mHeight * 4);      // mData is only allocated once in constructor
...
totalB += mData[x + y * mWidth];
```

The cpu usage became 22-25%.

Is it possible to reduce the cpu usage down close to 10 again? Somehow access the data much quicker? Should I try using asm?

Other info: The video is 10bit 1280 X 720 using GraphEdit to test my filter.
My filter does not change the source image (so it does not copy).
I may thread this process if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

For more info, I added the directshow graph. The video is 10bit but the Lav filters pass RGB32 (8bit) to me. It is debug build, would release speed it up (eventually I will compile to release build).

[image]

I ran the 2 different ways (mentioned earlier) and benchmarked their elapsed time. With dereferencing I get around 0.126208 milliseconds for each time transform runs. Without the dereferencing I get 0.009 milliseconds.

I also tried to reduce the loops by doing

```
for (int c = 0; c < roi.width; c += 4) {
    totalB += pixel[c] + pixel[c + 3] + pixel[c + 6] + pixel[c + 9];
    totalG += pixel[c + 1] + pixel[c + 4] + pixel[c + 7] + pixel[c + 10];
    totalR += pixel[c + 2] + pixel[c + 5] + pixel[c + 8] + pixel[c + 11];
}
```

This did not change the CPU usage and the elapsed time is still around 0.12

**Edit 2:**

I also built all dependencies and the project itself in release and i get the same result. Still very slow access.

Comment: That's pretty slow, you normally want SIMD optimization here. Also note that while you are saying it's 10-bit video, you are doing 8-bit math, so there is also an extra converter/decoder on the way.

Comment: What about doing: http://ideone.com/lVmT2e

Comment: Is this a debug or release build ?

Comment: Checking the cpu usage is not a good way to get insight on algorithm efficiency, you'd better check the running time.

Comment: its 10bit video but the other filters used (Lav filters) convert it to 8bit. It is debug build.

Comment: @user: Debug builds (normally) aren't optimized. Always measure performance bottlenecks in optimized code! What are the results like for Release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. So the problem was that the data was a pointer pointing to data in video memory. I was trying to use data and transferring it from video to computer RAM causing memory bandwidth errors. Copy all the data at once (memcpy) was faster but still very slow. Instead I had to use specific Intel SSE4 commands to efficiently copy the data from video memory to computer memory.

I used [this file](http://lavfilters.googlecode.com/git-history/0.49/common/DSUtilLite/gpu_memcpy_sse4.h) (gpu_memcpy). It contains a similar function to memcpy but uses the GPU to do the work. It is much faster and after copying, accessing the data is fast as usual.